# Java Passing objects to a method

Tags: java, polymorphism

Suppose that X and Y are classes such that Y extends X. Also, let method(X xObj) be a method of X. Why does the following code compile?

```
X xObj = new X();
Y yObj = new Y();
xObj.method(yObj);
```

Also, are there other similar cases in which code that seems incorrect compiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Y` extends `X`, then, `Y` *is* an `X`. You can substitute `X` for `Y` (consistantly) in any application.

You can do all this fancy stuff:

```
X object = new Y();
object.method(object)
Y objY = new Y();
object.method(objY);
objY.method(object);
```

The main thing to note is that *a child class is the type of it's parent*.

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter for `method()` is of type `X`, any object that is a subtype of `X` (`Y`, in the example) is also valid as argument.

Note that you can also do:

```
X yObj = new Y(); // declare variable yObj with type X and reference Y instance
xObj.method(yObj);
```

Take, for example, the `Integer` class. `Integer` extends `Number`, and `Number` implicitly extends `Object`. Any object of type `Integer` is also a `Number` and also an `Object`. So you could do:

```
static void print(Object obj) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

And call:

```
Integer n = 5;
print(n);
```

Output:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

The type of a method parameter always matches its subtypes. That means a method which matches X will match its subclass Y. This is because, to the compiler, a Y is guaranteed to act like an X, as that's one of the fundamental  contracts of OOP.